# Copying record and keeping relationships in tact

Tags: entity-framework

I am finding difficulty in copying records and keeping the current relationships in tact. I'm not even sure what I need to do can be done.

My database is quite large, but I will limit my example to 3 tables. Below are the classes representing those tables.

```
public class FiscalYear
{
    public FiscalYear()
    {
        this.Divisions = new HashSet<Division>();
    }

    public int FiscalYearId { get; set; };

    ...other members....

    public virtual ICollection<Division> Divisions { get; set; }
    ...more Navigation properties...
}

public class Division
{
    public Division()
    {
        this.Majors = new HashSet<Major>();
    }

    public int DivisionId { get; set; };
    public int FiscalYearId { get; set; }

    ...other members....

    public virtual ICollection<Major> Majors { get; set; }
    public virtual FiscalYear FiscalYear { get; set; }
    ...more Navigation properties...
}

public class Major
{
    public Major()
    {
        this.Courses = new HashSet<Course>();
    }

    public int MajorId { get; set; };
    public int FiscalYearId { get; set; }

    ...other members....

    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public virtual FiscalYear FiscalYear { get; set; }
    ...more Navigation properties...
}
```

Several of the database's tables are tied to a fiscal year. What I am trying to do is copy a record from one fiscal year into the next. So, for example, if I have a fiscal year of 2012 defined
and a division defined in 2012 such as IT, I would like to be able to create a new Fiscal Year - say 2013 - and copy all relationships from the 2012 to the 2013. But the problem lies in the level down in the hierarchy. Each division has many majors, but those majors are tied to fiscal year as well. So, I would need to also create new records for Fiscal Year 2013 for Majors and have these new records tied to the new 2013 Division but have the same relationships as the 2012 division. And so on and on.

Can something like this be done? I apologize if this is confusing as hell - it was too me.

Comment: So basically someone tightly coupled two tables together and you are trying to just hack this together for this one year? Why not refactor the design so that it is properly normalized and can support this type of manipulation in the future? As it lays, it seems like there is a lot of data duplication in the system. I know it seems like a lot of work to refactor, but it needs it. Remove the dependency on FiscalYear and instead create a new table which can facilitate the many to many relationship present there. Either that, or accept that each year is different, and create instead of copy.

Comment: @Travis No, not just one year....every year. Every division, major, course, etc. can change from fiscal year to fiscal year, but can stay the same - that's why it was developed this way - they have to be tied to a fiscal year. So, instead of them having to recreate each year manually every fiscal year, they want a tool to do this. I am by no means a master database designer so forgive my daftness - what is not properly normalized about the current structure? Thank you for the response.

Comment: Sorry if I am not accurate, I only get to see this little snippet of the architecture to infer from. I understand it is hard, or sometimes not even possible, to post a complete architecture. In my opinion there should be a linking table, which makes the relationship between, in this one example, Division and FiscalYear. This would enable any division to be used in any year (hence many-to-many). I would do this in any place where a one-one was made instead of what should be, in my opinion, a many to many.

Comment: I can see that....but it would get messy. A division has many majors, a major has many courses, a course has many prerequisites which has many courses. The structure goes many layers which I haven't listed (there's 65 tables total in this database) that it seems there would be numerous linking tables and linking tables to map to other linking tables :) But, to make things short, is there not a way in EF that can accomplish what I want without having to write a horrendous pot of code to map each relationship?

Comment: Just going to have to write the horrendous code. Start at the least dependent table, and move out from there to keep the foreign keys in state and enforce the referential integrity.